# Subclassing and generics

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, subclass

**Please note**: although this question deals specifically with [Hystrix](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix), its really more about Java generics and can be answered as such.

I am trying to subclass [`HystrixCommand`](http://netflix.github.io/Hystrix/javadoc/index.html?com/netflix/hystrix/HystrixCommand.html) with a `BaseCommand` that can then be subclassed by the rest of my app. This `BaseCommand` will include all sorts of goodies that the other command subclasses can inherit for free.

My best attempt so far:

```
public class BaseCommand<T> extends HystrixCommand<T> {
    // Stuff
}

public class FunnyCommand<Widget> extends BaseCommand<Widget> {
    // Stuff
}
```

But this produces the following compiler error:

> The class com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCircuitBreaker$UnitTest$BaseCommand refers to the class com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCircuitBreaker$UnitTest$BaseCommand and uses 1 parameters, but the referred class takes no parameters

It also produces the following compiler warning:

> The type parameter String is hiding the type String

How can I rewrite this so:

1. `BaseCommand` and `HystrixCommand` are generic for *any* type (`T`, `?`, etc.); and
2. `BaseCommand` subclasses are generic for *any* concrete type (String, Long, Widget, etc.); and
3. No compiler errors or warnings exist

On Java 7 here.

Comment: Please show your actual code or actual error. The second error cannot apply to the code you've shown.

Comment: This `FunnyCommand<Widget>` declares a type parameter called `Widget` independent of any `Widget` type you've declared anywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class FunnyCommand extends BaseCommand<Widget> {
```

`Widget` is just a type, so you don't need to declare it as a type variable. The an unfortunate C-like thing that declaration and use look similar.

In the following code, the identifier `T` is used in two different roles.

```
public class BaseCommand<T> extends HystrixCommand<T> {
                         ^ declare T               ^use T
```

Comment: Thanks @Tom Hawtin - tackline (+1) - however when I change `FunnyCommand<Widget>` to `FunnyCommand` I still get the same error. Ideas?

Comment: @IAmYourFaja Um, dunno. Looks a strange error. A quick google shows it being related to a bug in oldish versions of NetBeans. Are you using that? If so upgrading to a newish version may fix it.